# Metamask Failed transaction when sending out BAT tokens

Tags: gas, metamask, out-of-gas, basic-attention-token

I've been trying to send some BAT tokens out of my metamask wallet for quite awhile and it keeps eating up all my eth gas fees. I even increased the gwei fee to 100 and paid .50 USD as the fee. And it still failed.

What am I doing wrong? It would be nice, if it gave the correct amount of gas I need in order to send it instead of guess. This is kinda ridiculous that I lose out on my fees.

Also do different tokens charge different gas fees? I see that BNB gas fees are $1-$10 when I try to send it.

[image: Is there some type of service that can monitor my account for only incoming transactions to my address? I found a few, but they also email me when I send something out which can be annoying.]

Comment: can you please share the transaction hashes.

Comment: Just increase the `gas limit` and i think it will solve your issue. Don't increase the `gas price` unless you want the transaction to mined immediately

Comment: increase it to what ? by 2x?

Comment: You have GAS Limit  35,907 - it's very small vor transfer token.

For example, a transaction that has completed successfully spent
95,907 gas.
I think the limit of 150,000 will be optimal.

Comment: ok thanks. that works. but imagine a newbie sending tokens, they would have no idea about this. It doesnt even give hints to how to fix it. totally bad user experience. how is eth ever going to gain adoption due to these issues.

Comment: yeah the UX here is horrible, I wonder if there's a github issue open about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to the GAS LIMIT issue, I set it to 2x of what it was at 70k and it works now. 35k and under is too low.

Comment: this setting is in "Advanced options" below the fee selection